# how to echo the file name that includes a file [changing page title depending on file running]

Tags: php

I tried using php predefined variables but no function seems to work for me.

index.php, page2.php, page3.php contains:

```
include 'header.php';
```

now, i want my header.php to echo different title tags depending which file called it.

I tried running echo **FILE** but echo header.php, rather than index.php or page2.php,.. etc.

is there a way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is set a variable like `$title` on every of your pages (i.e. `index.php`, `page2.php` and `page3.php`) with your desired title and then echo this variable in the `header.php` like this (example for `index.php`):

```
$title = "Welcome Page";
include("header.php");
```

And in `header.php`:

```
echo $title;
```

To my knowledge there is no way in determining which file `A` included an other file `B` from within file `B`. For the opposite, determining all included files there however exists the function [`get_included_files()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php).

Comment: LOL, this is simpler than looking for the answer to my question.