# echo name of file 'including' not 'included'

Tags: php

Ok so I am making a website on each page where I want to `include` a file sidebar.php .

In sidebar.php I would like to echo the name of file that included sidebar.php .

Below are contents of sidebar.php, they return 'sidebar'.

```
<?php 
$file = basename(__FILE__, '.php');
echo $file;
;?>
```

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059197/how-to-echo-the-file-name-that-includes-a-file-changing-page-title-depending-on) but the whole point is that I don't have to make no variables in on each page.

Excuse me for vague use of word 'include', I am using the it as the statement in [php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). *Why* do you need this? There's probably a better way.

Comment: Is the file which includes `sidebar.php` the script requested in the URI? `$_SERVER` may already have the value you want (though like @h2ooooooo, I suspect there's a better approach)

Comment: h2ooooooo I am willing to say that you are right.

Comment: As for why do I need it: its because I want contents of sidebar to be reusable, they will contain instruction on how to use the page, but I would like to be able to display these instructions on on a single manual page, for user continence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass it to the sidebar page through a session variable:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['filename'] = "thisFilesName.php";
    include('../sidebar.php');
?>
```

sidebar.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['filename'];
?>
```

Comment: John, Do you think there is a way getting this done without including php outside of the sidebar.php?

Comment: Are you saying that you would like the only line of php code on the parent page to be `include 'sidebar.php';` ??

Comment: Why use a session variable considering that it includes sidebar anyway? All you're forcing is the user to have a session cookie. Just use a regular variable.

Comment: h2ooooooo yes I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: John Carroll yes that is what I am trying to do